# Change text shown while liking a page

Tags: facebook-like

I have used fb like button in my website.But while clicking the button the link of my page is shown in the face book.I need to change the link to a text with hyperlink to my site.How can I implement this ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/), and [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Answer (score 0):

To customise the appearance of the Like story you need to add Open Graph meta tags to your HTML head:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/

Comment: Thanks Mathew.But I have included Open Graph meta tags in HTML head but still the I'm getting the link only and not the text which I have provided.Do you know the reason ??

Comment: You can use the Open Graph Debug tool to check why your tags aren't correct:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug  
You'll need to provide a URL if you want us to look at this for you

Comment: Thank you Mathew.I got it debugged.